# iOS official to-do tutorial: List View Controller does not display correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've been trying to learn iOS app development and i started from the official tutorial of Apple from this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html

It's a 3 step tutorial. I followed each one's instructions as they are but at the end of 3rd tutorial, i cannot get correct output from my app. The tutorial says it should look like this when it's over: [image]

.

But my app looks like this: [image]

.

I cannot add new item. Below you can see my storyboard and all my code. But you can also download whole project from here: [***Link***](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w890pqpcopen8ch/ToDoList.zip)

If it helps, i'm working on OS X 10.9.2 with Xcode 5.0.2

My storyboard:

[image]

XYZAddToDoItemViewController.m file's code:

```
    #import "XYZAddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

@end


@implementation XYZAddToDoItemViewController

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.doneButton) return;
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
        self.toDoItem = [[XYZToDoItem alloc] init];
        self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
        self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
    }
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

XYZAddToDoItemViewController.h file's code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XYZToDoItem.h"

@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController : UIViewController


@property XYZToDoItem *toDoItem;


@end
```

XYZToDoItem.m file's code:

```
#import "XYZToDoItem.h"

@implementation XYZToDoItem

@end
```

XYZToDoItem.h file's code:

```
// This class creates and stores the data for individual list items.

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYZToDoItem : NSObject

@property NSString *itemName;
@property BOOL completed;
@property (readonly) NSDate *creationDate;

@end
```

XYZToDoListViewController.m file's code:

```
#import "XYZToDoListViewController.h"
#import "XYZAddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface XYZToDoListViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

@end

@implementation XYZToDoListViewController

- (void)loadInitialData {
    XYZToDoItem *item1 = [[XYZToDoItem alloc] init];
    item1.itemName = @"Buy milk";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];
    XYZToDoItem *item2 = [[XYZToDoItem alloc] init];
    item2.itemName = @"Buy eggs";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item2];
    XYZToDoItem *item3 = [[XYZToDoItem alloc] init];
    item3.itemName = @"Read a book";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item3];
}

- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    XYZAddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    XYZToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;
    if (item != nil) {
        [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self loadInitialData];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.

    // it changes when i comment following line!!
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.toDoItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    XYZToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;

    if (toDoItem.completed) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

//
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
//

//
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
//

//
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
//

//
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
//

//
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

//



#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    XYZToDoItem *tappedItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
@end
```

XYZToDoListViewController.h file's code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XYZToDoItem.h"

@interface XYZToDoListViewController : UITableViewController
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;

@property XYZToDoItem *toDoItem;

@end
```

XYZAppDelegate.m file's code:

```
#import "XYZAppDelegate.h"

@implementation XYZAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

XYZAppDelegate.h file's code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XYZAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Comment: seriously guys, still no answer? :o

Comment: I have gone through ToDoList apple document but did't find source download. Where did you got source code downloaded from?

Comment: i didn't download it. i followed tutorial and write 'em all by myself

Answer (score 1):

I think Apple forgot one step in the tutorial. In order to add items, you must link your done button to the method `unwindToList`.

All you do is go to your storyboard and Ctrl-click Done and drag it to the Exit icon on your XYZAddToDoItemViewController. A menu "ActionSegue" should appear with your unwindToDoList method.
Just drag the line over that method, then release, and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

XYZToDoListViewController.m file's code: seems to be missing an import for XYZToDoItem.h - It looks like it was added to XYZToDoListViewController.h instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have not followed the tutorial properly. You had make a mistake which I have had done too.

Mistake:
You have used the `+` symbol in Bar Item's "Title".

Solution:
Select Add From Identifier's drop down list , and re-follow the tutorial again.

It should work!